# Nginx docker variable substitution does not work

Tags: docker, nginx, envsubst

I'm struggling with Nginx docker environment variable substitution, it somehow does not work for me. I'm using nginx version 1.25.3 in a custom dockerfile where I copy my template nginx config file like that:

```
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.25.3
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}

ARG SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY=data/scrypts
COPY ["./${SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY}/99-autoreload.sh", "/docker-entrypoint.d/99-autoreload.sh"]
RUN chmod 755 /docker-entrypoint.d/99-autoreload.sh

ARG TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY=data/nginx
COPY ["./${TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY}/server.conf.template", "/etc/nginx/templates/server.conf.template"]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then in my docker compose file I set some nginx environment variables like that:

```
   environment:
      - NGINX_CONFIG_SERVER_NAME:${NGINX_CONFIG_SERVER_NAME}
      - NGINX_CONFIG_LINUX_HOST:${NGINX_CONFIG_LINUX_HOST}
      - NGINX_CONFIG_WINDOWS_HOST:${NGINX_CONFIG_WINDOWS_HOST}
      - LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE:${LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE}
      - LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT:${LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT}
      - WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE:${WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE}
      - WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT:${WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT}
```

Then when I run docker-compose up I use env file with values for that. I do not updated command for nginx in docker-compose (since that can broke nginx startup scripts).

I checked out the logs of container and it stated nginx did run variable substitution:

```
...
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/server.conf.template to /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
...
2023/12/11 14:46:34 [emerg] 1#1: unknown "nginx_config_linux_host" variable
nginx: [emerg] unknown "nginx_config_linux_host" variable
```

When I inspected the container, variables are set there correctly, but it looks like nginx does not see environment variables and not set it, as when I inspected the config file it was exctracted from template, but the content was untouched.

My config for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ${NGINX_CONFIG_SERVER_NAME};

    #For test purposes only, update later
    location ${LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE} {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        proxy_pass http://${NGINX_CONFIG_LINUX_HOST}:${LINUX_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT}/;
    }

    #For test purposes only, update later
    location ${WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_ROUTE} {
        proxy_pass http://${NGINX_CONFIG_WINDOWS_HOST}:${WINDOWS_EXAMPLE_SERVICE_PORT}/;
    }
}
```

Any clues why it didn't work? My best guess is envsubst command somehow does not see my variables. What am I missing?

Comment: You have invalid syntax in your `environment` section; refer to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) for the two accepted mechanisms for setting variables (you can either have a dictionary or a list, but you have configured a list of dictionaries).

Comment: ...if you intend to use YAML dictionary syntax, also note that there must be a space after the colon.  If you're just passing through variables from the host, a list of simple strings without values `- NGINX_CONFIG_LINUX_HOST` will work as well.  This is detailed in the linked documentation.

Comment: Great, it was actually that thing... Thank you guys! :)